# Build grid tile with overlaying buttons

Tags: html, css, overlay

I am trying to build myself a portfolio websitefor my work and learn HTML, CSS, and js at the same time. I am trying to recreate the portfolio tile listing found on this [website](http://findmatthew.com/).

I am trying to use a CSS grid to recreate this. I am following this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bam83Xv4VMA&list=PLuqEQ3Xb5hREAEuxwS70poa7v3x8rWsV6&index=41&t=927s).

The main difference is I am trying to set the image to be used for the card/tile as the background (done in CSS) and not via an image in the HTML. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong and would appreciate any insight. Also is there a way to confirm that you CSS is currently linked to your HTML file? The following is my current output:

[image]

HTML code:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  margin: 100px;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

h1 {
  margin: 5rem;
}

.portfolio {
  width: 300px;
  height: 10vh;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(19rem, 1fr));
  .AutoFP {
    background: url(http://freeaussiestock.com/free/Victoria/Melbourne/slides/fed_square.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .fpl-1 {
    background: url(https://media.defense.gov/2013/Jul/16/2000032379/-1/-1/0/130628-F-DQ639-002.JPG) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .fpl-3 {
    background: url(https://s0.geograph.org.uk/geophotos/03/25/64/3256477_ec7d83ab.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .fpl-4 {
    background: url(http://freeaussiestock.com/free/Victoria/Melbourne/slides/melbourne_museum_roof.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .card:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.scss">

    <title>Portfolio Tiles</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Where the tiles will go shocasing work -->
    <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
      <!-- Tile 1 -->
      <div class="AutoFP card">
        <h3 class="card-heading">Automated FlightPlanning</h3>
        <span>Electron, Python</span>
        <button class="card-btn" id="AutoFP">Learn More</button>
      </div>
      <!-- Tile 2 -->
      <div class="fpl-1">
        <h3 class="card-heading card">Flight Plan 1</h3>
        <span>DJIFlightplanner python</span>
        <button class="card-btn" id="AutoFP">Learn More</button>
      </div>
      <!-- Tile 3 -->
      <div class="fpl-2 card">
        <h3 class="card-heading">Flight Plan 2</h3>
        <span>DJIFlightplanner python</span>
        <button class="card-btn" id="AutoFP">Learn More</button>
      </div>
      <!-- Tile 4 -->
      <div class="fpl-3 card">
        <h3 class="card-heading">Flight Plan 3</h3>
        <span>DJIFlightplanner python</span>
        <button class="card-btn" id="AutoFP">Learn More</button>
      </div>

    </section>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @cristian mocanu, you have a syntax error in your CSS.

Nesting css rules only works if you're using a preprocessor like sass/scss (with a few exceptions like media queries), but that only works if you *process* your CSS before it gets to the browser. Browsers understand css, not sass. It may be helpful to avoid preprocessors until you're more comfortable with css and working in the browser, since it adds a layer of complexity.

Using the page inspector in your browser's [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (F12) will help you test whether your css is valid, Firefox even has a grid inspector that helps you use css grid and shows the grid lines on the screen - the [layout land](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7TizprGknbDalbHplROtag) youtube channel has a video about how to use it.

You can also use the network tab of your developer tools to see what files are being loaded on the page (this might have a different name depending on the browser, I think in chrome it's called sources ?).

I edited your code a little - it may be simpler for you to use media queries to set the number of columns in your grid rather than working with auto-fit. The "card" class was applied inconsistently in your divs so the opacity wasn't working on each tile.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  margin: 100px;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

h1 {
  margin: 5rem;
}

.portfolio {
  width: 300px;
  height: 10vh;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(19rem, 1fr));
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 }
.portfolio .AutoFP {
  background: url(http://freeaussiestock.com/free/Victoria/Melbourne/slides/fed_square.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.portfolio .fpl-1 {
  background: url(https://media.defense.gov/2013/Jul/16/2000032379/-1/-1/0/130628-F-DQ639-002.JPG) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.portfolio .fpl-3 {
  background: url(https://s0.geograph.org.uk/geophotos/03/25/64/3256477_ec7d83ab.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
.portfolio .fpl-4 {
  background: url(http://freeaussiestock.com/free/Victoria/Melbourne/slides/melbourne_museum_roof.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
.portfolio .card:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <!-- Where the tiles will go shocasing work -->
    <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
      <!-- Tile 1 -->
      <div class="AutoFP card">
        <h3 class="card-heading">Automated FlightPlanning</h3>
        <span>Electron, Python</span>
        <button class="card-btn" id="AutoFP">Learn More</button>
      </div>
      <!-- Tile 2 -->
      <div class="fpl-1 card">
        <h3 class="card-heading">Flight Plan 1</h3>
        <span>DJIFlightplanner python</span>
        <button class="card-btn" id="AutoFP">Learn More</button>
      </div>
      <!-- Tile 3 -->
      <div class="fpl-2 card">
        <h3 class="card-heading">Flight Plan 2</h3>
        <span>DJIFlightplanner python</span>
        <button class="card-btn" id="AutoFP">Learn More</button>
      </div>
      <!-- Tile 4 -->
      <div class="fpl-3 card">
        <h3 class="card-heading">Flight Plan 3</h3>
        <span>DJIFlightplanner python</span>
        <button class="card-btn" id="AutoFP">Learn More</button>
      </div>

    </section>
  </body>
```

Answer (score -2):

In CSS you must end the definition of one class before starting another. In your CSS after the grid-template-columns line you have to use '}', and remove the '}' at the end.

Comment: If I am using cscc style is that still needed? My hope was to nest the classes.

Comment: @C.Radford If you are using scss its perfectly fine to nest classes